# Android - Having Trouble In Stopping Soundpool COrrectly

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, android-handler, soundpool

**<< Here Is My Code >>**

```
Handler HC1;
int streamId;
```

**In onCreate I Have**

```
HC1 = new Handler();
```

**In Another Class Outside onCreate But In Same Activity I Have**

```
public class MyTouchListene implements OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.C1:

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        streamId = sp.play(pianoSound[keyNumber], 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                        break;


                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        HC1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                sp.stop(streamId);
                            }
                        }, 500);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**And My Problem Is**

I've 6 secs long audio in soundpool

When I touch the button for first audio starts playing, when I take my finger up audio stops after 500 milliseconds, As written in code but when I double tap the button same audio starts twice (As I Want) but the audio started after first gets stopped after 500 milliseconds but the first audio doesn't stops until it gets finished. why? help me

I want something like this...

*if I touch button at 0 milliseconds audio starts, then pick up my finger at 250 millisecs so audio gets stopped at 750 millisecs...
but if I touch button at 0 millisecs pick up at 250 millisecs and touch again at 250 millisecs and pick up at 750 so two audio play at that time one stops at 750 millisecs and another stops at 1250 millisecs*

Waiting...
Thanks In Advance...